# ExtJS: Validate full hour time

Tags: javascript, regex, extjs

I am trying to create a form in ExtJS with a time field. This time field should only accept full hours.

It is configured like this:

```
{
    name: 'validFromTime',
    fieldLabel: 'Valid From Time',
    xtype: 'timefield',
    increment: 60,
    allowBlank: false
}
```

The 60 minute increment only affects the picker UI, but not the validation. Thus, I have to validate myself to prevent the user from typing something like 1:20 AM into the time field.

I tried to do that with the following regex config:

```
{
    name: 'validFromTime',
    fieldLabel: 'Valid From Time',
    xtype: 'timefield',
    increment: 60,
    regex: /^([1-9]|1[0-2]):(00)\s([A|P]M)$/,
    invalidText: 'Must be a full hour in format "1:00 AM/PM".',
    allowBlank: false
}
```

According to this online regex checker, this regex is correct: https://regex101.com/r/uR9sM0/1

However, ExtJS now always marks this field as invalid, even when the user selects a correct time like 11:00 AM.

To isolate the problem, I tried to match a little bit less. The most I can get working is this:

```
/([1-9]|1[0-2]):00.*/
```

As soon as I add any of the other parts, like the ^ or the \s, it doesn't work anymore. Any ideas on what I am missing?

Comment: Have you checked what is the text in the field?

Comment: Could it be as simple as a matter of the case of AM/PM? You haven't specified case insensitive in the regex.

Comment: The value of the field is a Date object.

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle to work with: http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/pt6bze6f/ The field validation for the regular expression must apply to the `getValue()` rather than the `getSubmitValue()` method on the time field.

Comment: Your regex (`/([1-9]|1[0-2]):00.*/`) works, because it is a partial regular expression that is validating the `"00:00"` portion of the `toString()` for date object i.e. `"Tue Jan 01 2008 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"`.

Comment: Phew. Is that string even stable to match upon? It might depend on browser / locale / whatnot else? Just for correctness: the time format should be 'g:i A' instead of 'h:i A'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments already, the underlying value of a time field is a Date object. Therefore I'd recommend to validate the Date object instead of the input text, not only because it's much easier than building a regex but also because the timefield recognizes some additional input patterns other than the displayed format (see the [`format`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Time-cfg-format) and [`altFormats`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Time-cfg-altFormats) config options) which would be prevented altogether when using a regex validation.

You can use the [`validator`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Time-cfg-validator) config option to provide a function used for your custom validation(s) which will be run in addition to the field's built-in validations:

```
validator: function() {
    var value = this.getValue();

    if (Ext.isDate(value) && value.getMinutes() !== 0) {
        return 'Must be a full hour in format "1:00 AM/PM".';
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that the check for the object type is mandatory, because `value` will not be a date object if the field is unable to parse the user's input.

**Fiddle:** https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/pu2